# How to allow cookies in windows 8 c# app or click a html button via c# code

Tags: c#, windows-8, httpclient

I have a web page with this part of code:

```
<form action="/?cid=2000" id="queryForm">
<div><button type="submit" name="computeTrip" value="true" class="button">compute trip </button></div></form>
```

I need to run this in my c# app. I  tried a POST method but it doesnt work. (I think I could do it wrong).
To achive next page I wanted to download code in first page,to make changes in http adress  and next run second page. But I have to alllow cookies.

I use Http Client sample from msdn.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Post the C# code that your tried to use.  HttpClient is the right approach.